# Django delete and then redirect

Tags: django

I have a case that I do not know how to resolve in django. The user is working in a form and then once the form is finished the user is able to generate a PDF from the data from the form. I would like to redirect the user to another page because once the document is generated there is no need to say in the form page.

views.py

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=" + filename +'.pdf'
response.write(pdf)

return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect in your view function with Django built in [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=" + filename +'.pdf'
response.write(pdf)

return HttpResponseRedirect("/some-url")
```